# Linking buttons of a UserControl to functions on a parent control

Tags: asp.net

I've got a User Control with Save and Cancel buttons that I'm displaying in another user control. When the user hits Save, I want the inner user control to do it's standard functionality but I would also like the parent control to do some things. What's the best way to handle this?

Comment: The best approach is raising a custom _save_-event that you can handle in the "outer" control. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8797/Mastering-Page-UserControl-Communication#4.3

Comment: You could have the parent implement an interface with the functionality you want, and in your user control have a property of that interface to reference the parent page. Then from within your child method, you can call your property that references the parent and call the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best approach is raising a custom *save*-event that you can handle in the "outer" control.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8797/Mastering-Page-UserControl-Communication#4.3

The advantage of this event-approach is that UserControls remain being reusable. You can use UserControl A in other pages(or UserControls) as well even when they don't handle this event. It's part of the controller to decide what is needed and what should be done.

UserControls as a rule should not depend on specific controllers, otherwise they are hard-linked and not reusable. That would be also a good source for nasty erros. A UserControl might be a controller for other nested (User-)Controls but not for the page itself.

**Communication Summary**:

- Page -> UserControl -> public properties and methods
- UserControl -> Page -> Events
- UserControl -> UserControl -> the controller-UserControl adopts the page-role(see above, your use-case)

Answer (score 0):

Bubble Events fit the bill, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719644(v=vs.71).aspx

You can raise a bubble event in your user control and it will recursively be passed to each of the user control's ancestors until it's handled